# How to get my topic name from message header and publish

Tags: json, apache-kafka, http-headers, spring-integration, kafka-producer-api

I am new to spring-integration. I am trying to build a spring rest service where it will get any HTTP requests with some json message and publish to kafka topic.

My json message will be posted thru RequestBody which will contain the topic name in the message header.

I am able to post the message from my controller to kafka channel, however I am getting hard time to get the topic name from my json message header.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the topic name from my message header (typically a HTTP request consists a json message with topic name) and use the topic to publish the message.

my json :

```
{"resourceType": "MessageHeader",
"topicName": "testToptic",
"messagePayload":{
    "location": "chennai",
    "messageDetail": {
        "department-id": 123,
        "department-name": "SSS",
        "pincode": 600009
    }
}
}}
```

here my bean and handler

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow hanldeGenericKafka() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(sendToKafkaChannel)

            .handle(
                    kafkaGenericMessageHandler(producerFactory),
                    e -> e.id("kafkaProducer2"))
            .get();
}

public KafkaProducerMessageHandlerTemplateSpec<String, String> kafkaGenericMessageHandler(
        ProducerFactory<String, String> producer) {

    return Kafka
            .outboundChannelAdapter(producer)
            .sync(true)
            .headerMapper(kafkaDefaultHeaderMapper())
            .messageKey(m -> m.getHeaders()
                    .get("topicname"))
            .configureKafkaTemplate(t -> t.id("kafkaTemplate"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression with the built-in [JsonPath SpEL function](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#built-in-spel-functions) to extract a field value from a JSON payload.

Use the expression in the adapter's `.topicExpression()`.